# Recover a wallet using the 12 words

Tags: blockchain.info

I have a blockchain wallet with some unconfirmed transactions (with zero confirmation). If I recover the wallet in another brandname of wallet with the recovery phrase of 12 words, will the unconfirmed transaction appear in the new wallet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I did this using a Blockchain.info wallet and was able to run it simultaneously on Coinomi app.

Answer (score 0):

You could restore the wallet in electrum and do a [child pays for parent](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/5zchm8/sent_transaction_with_low_fees_in_electrum_can_i/dex2alq/) transaction to bump the fee on the unconfirmed transaction.

Note that during seed entry stage of the wallet restoration process click on options and check bip39.

Comment: Can you tell me more about "bip39"?

Comment: @Roger Wong It's a standard for seed mnemonics that blockchain.info and a lot of other wallets use. Electrum doesn't use it for its native seeds but lets you restore from other wallets that do follow that standard. You can learn more about bip39 here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki